# File Upload Cross Domain

Tags: silverlight, file-upload

The scenario I am trying to create is to have my Silverlight Website on one domain and my file server (for media files) on a different server.  I want to allow my users to upload files to the file server from the website.

The problem is I am getting a generic "Security error." reported back in the inner exception message in my code.  The main exception message is blank.

I have set all access right to the physical folders (Windows Server 2008).  I have created wide-open clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files.

I am using an .ashx handler for doing the actual writing to the hard drive.  I have tested it locally on the file server machine and it works fine.

I have root level access to both servers so I can make any changes required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Silverlight programmer, but I might be able to help here... Browser security prevents pretty much any cross-domain actions like this. It's to prevent phishing.

What you could do to get around this is to create another hostname on the same domain as your webserver and proxy any requests on your webserver to your file server. That would get around the cross-domain problem.

Comment: Thanks Rob, looking into it. Can you explain how the proxy would work?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... are you using Apache or IIS?